# SUM & Count expiryAmt if expiryAmt is greater than 2% of orderAmt

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with 2 tables:

- **suporder** which contains order data (PK: Id)

  - Has a column for the orders value called `orderamt`
- **supexpiry** which holds expiry data (FK orderid references suporder.Id)

  - Has a column for the expiry value called `expiryamt`

I have the query below working, but I am stuck on an additional requirement I have. I need to retrieve the COUNT & SUM of `supexpiry.expiryamt` where `supexpiry.expiryamt` is greater than 2% of the relevant `suporder.orderamt`.

```
select distinct(s.merchantId::int), s.merchantName, count(s.id)::int as orderCount, sum(s.orderamt) as orderAmt, count(s2.orderid)::int as expiryCount, sum(s2.expiredamt) as expiryAmt
from suporder s 
left join supexpiry s2 on s2.orderid = s.id
where s.orderdate >= '2021-09-01'::date and s.orderdate <= '2021-10-13'::date
group by s.merchantid, s.merchantname
```

So ideally the output would look like the following (with the last 2 being the new columns):

| merchant | merchantname | ordercount | orderamt | expirycount | expiryamt | expiry>2%count | expiry>2%amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | Marcs & Spencer | 144737 | 2259026472 | 17650 | 20596768 | 13232 | 18344568 |
| 5345512331 | Amazon | 5123 | 27999459 | 873 | 14871 | 795 | 13555 |

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That distinct keyword isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Add a filter condition to the aggregates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `count(s2.orderid)` to `sum(case when s2.expiredamt/s.orderamt > .02 then 1 else 0 end)`
and `sum(s2.expiredamt)` to `sum(case when s2.expiredamt/s.orderamt > .02 then s2.expiredamt else 0 end)`

Or, if you don't like repetition, you can `cross join lateral (values (case when s2.expiredamt/s.orderamt > .02 then 1 else 0 end)) expired(multiplier)` and then use `sum(expired.multiplier)` and `sum(expired.multiplier * s2.expiredamt)`

Comment: Works great thanks so much Bill!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue you are encountering is that you want to filter your data after grouping it using the "group by" clause. That is, after data has been [aggregated](https://www.xplenty.com/glossary/what-is-sql-aggregation/).
To do the kind of filtering you want, you'll need to use the [having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) keyword. Having is basically the same as where, except that it works on data after it has been aggregated.

So your query will look like

```
select...
where...
group by...
having...
```